# Compact generator of $D(\mathbb{P}^1)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, tilting, derived-categories

I suppose that Beilinson's compact generator (and, in fact, tilting object) $\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(1)$ in $D(\mathbb{P}^1)$ is the most well known example. I have the following simple construction for compact generator (but not a tilting object) on projective line. Lets take any point $z \in \mathbb{P}^1$ and denote skyscraper sheaf at this point $k(z)$ then
$$
C=\mathcal{O} \oplus k(z)
$$
is a compact generator. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct.  Taking the cone of a map $k(z) \to O[1]$ you get $O(1)$. Thus both $O$ and $O(1)$ are contained in the subcategory generated by $C$, and since these two generate $D(P^1)$, the same is true for $C$.